# Cannot connect to DataLakeServiceClient with SAS token

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to implement an automation script and one of the tasks is to check the directory contents in a directory inside Azure Datalake. I am trying to connect to it via DataLakeServiceClient, unfortunately I am not able to and see the following answer

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

url_with_sas = "https://<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>?sp=racwdlmeop&st=2022-10-17T11:50:11Z&se=2022-10-17T19:50:11Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=<some_hash>"
account_url = 'https://<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/'
sas_token = '?sp=racwdlmeop&st=2022-10-17T11:50:11Z&se=2022-10-17T19:50:11Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=<some_hash>'

client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url, sas_token)
#Tried with credintionals separatedand inside url, in second option I recived 
#azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: The requested URI does not represent any 
#resource on the server.
#client = DataLakeServiceClient(url_with_sas)
print(client.get_service_properties())
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/plewkak/OneDrive - ZF Friedrichshafen AG/Desktop/IDA-automation-tool/aaaaa.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(client.get_service_properties())
  File "C:\Users\plewkak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\filedatalake\_data_lake_service_client.py", line 569, in get_service_properties
    props = self._blob_service_client.get_service_properties(**kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\plewkak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\plewkak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_blob_service_client.py", line 310, in get_service_properties
    process_storage_error(error)
  File "C:\Users\plewkak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\_shared\response_handlers.py", line 185, in process_storage_error
    exec("raise error from None")   # pylint: disable=exec-used # nosec
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:ab2261e5-101e-0053-1924-e2b0ce000000
Time:2022-10-17T12:34:45.3304352Z
ErrorCode:AuthenticationFailed
authenticationerrordetail:The specified signed resource is not allowed for the this resource level
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:ab2261e5-101e-0053-1924-e2b0ce000000
Time:2022-10-17T12:34:45.3304352Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The specified signed resource is not allowed for the this resource level</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

the same SAS works when I used it inside Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, I also was able to connect via DataLakeFileClient, when I added container name and path to file. However, DataLakeFileClient and DataLakeDirectoryClient doesn't give me any option to list all files in directory/subdirectory.

I would be extramly gratefull for any help. I used
Python 3.7.9
azure-storage-file-datalake 12.9.0

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because `get_service_properties` method is an operation on Storage Account itself ([`Get Account Information`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-account-information)) and you would need an [`Account SAS token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas) to perform this operation and currently you are performing this operation using a [`Service SAS token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas).

To fix this error, please use an `Account SAS token` with `SignedResourceTypes` with at least `Service` resource type.